# How to make sliding mechanic gain speed when on a slope

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a new unity developer that is trying to make a 3d game. So far I have managed to develop a pretty cool first-person character controller. It uses a character controller and it has sliding and jumping mechanics.

---

And the question is:

How can I make my player lose sliding speed when sliding up a slope and gain sliding speed when sliding down a slope?

---

Here is my code so far and please keep in mind that my code is messy and that I am a still beginner. If you need any further information please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks for your time! Also, any suggestions are more than welcome!

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Character controller refrence
    private CharacterController controller;
    //Camera refrence
    [SerializeField] Camera fpsCam;

    //IsGrounded variables
    private float groundDistance = 1.5f;
    public bool isGrounded;

    //SomethingAbove variables
    private float cellingDistance = 1.5f;
    public bool somethingAbove;

    //Variables
    //Speed that is modified
    private float speed = 12f;
    //Default speed
    private float baseSpeed = 12f;
    //Slide speed that is modified
    private float slideSpeed = 15f;
    //Default slide speed
    private float slideSpeedStorage = 15f;
    //Crouch speed
    private float crouchSpeed = 3f;
    //Jump height
    private float jumpHeight = 2f;
    private bool isJumping = false;
    //Gravity
    private float gravity = -14.715f;
    //Air resistance
    private float xAirResistance = 0.5f;
    private float zAirResistance = 0.35f;
    //Air multipiler
    private float airMultiplierJump = 1.1f;
    //Fov
    private float fovWhenSliding = 100f;
    private float defaultFov;
    //Crouch variables
    float originalHeight;
    float reducedHeight = 0.5f;

    //Player input
    float x;
    float z;
    bool jump;
    bool control;
    
    //Directions
    Vector3 velocity;
    private Vector3 move = new Vector3();
    private Vector3 slideDirection = new Vector3();
    private Vector3 jumpDirection = new Vector3();   

    private void Awake()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        //Getting the original height
        originalHeight = controller.height;

        //Getting the default fov
        defaultFov = fpsCam.fieldOfView;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        MyInput();
        Calculations();
        PlayerMovement();
    }

    private void MyInput()
    {
        //Getting WASD input
        x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        //Space bar input
        jump = Input.GetButtonDown("Jump");

        //Left control input
        control = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl);
    }

    private void Calculations()
    {
        //Checking if player is grounded
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.down * groundDistance, Color.red);
        isGrounded = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, groundDistance);
        //Checking if player can get up
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.up * cellingDistance, Color.black);
        somethingAbove = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.up, cellingDistance);

        /*//Getting the player has enough speed and getting jump direction
        if (isGrounded && jump && z > 0)
        {
            //If pressing W the jump direction is forward
            jumpDirection = transform.forward;
        }*/

        //Movement in air
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            //On ground movement
            move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
        }
        else
        {
            //If pressing W
            if (z > 0)
            {
                //Jump direction multiplied by airMultiplierJump
                move = transform.forward * z * airMultiplierJump + transform.right * x * xAirResistance;
            }
            else
            {
                //Jump direction = Vector3.zero;
                move = transform.forward * z * zAirResistance + transform.right * x * xAirResistance;
            }
        }

        //Checking if the player has enough speed for sliding and getting direction
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl) && isGrounded)
        {
            if (z == 1 || x == 1 || x == -1)
            {
                //If pressing W || A || D slide direction is the direction u are moving towards
                slideDirection = transform.forward * z + transform.right * x;
            }
            else
            {
                //If pressing S the slide direction is zero
                slideDirection = Vector3.zero;
            }
        }

        //Adding extra force so the player stays on ground
        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        //Calculating gravity
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        //Normalizing the move vector so the diagonal and normal movement are the same speed
        if (move.sqrMagnitude > 1)
        {
            move.Normalize();
        } 

        //Extra force on slope downwards so the player stays on it
        if((x != 0 || z != 0) && OnSlope())
        {
            controller.Move(Vector3.down * controller.height / 2 * 2f);
        }
    }

    private void PlayerMovement()
    {
        Jump();

        Slide();

        //Moving the player with WASD
        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        //Applying gravity
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void Slide()
    {
        //Checking for left control input and if the player is grounded
        if(control && isGrounded && !OnSlope())
        {
            StartSlide();
        }
        //Checking if the player can uncrouch
        else if(!somethingAbove && isGrounded)
        {
            StopSlide();
        }
        else if (!control)
        {
            controller.height = originalHeight;
            speed = baseSpeed;
        }
        else if(control && !isGrounded)
        {
            controller.height = originalHeight;
            speed = baseSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            controller.height = reducedHeight;
            speed = crouchSpeed;
        }
    }

    //Starting to slide
    private void StartSlide()
    {
        if (z != 1 || x != -1 || x != 1)
        {
            speed = crouchSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            speed = 0f;
        }

        controller.height = reducedHeight;
        controller.Move(slideDirection * Time.deltaTime * slideSpeed);
        slideSpeed -= 10f * Time.deltaTime;

        if (slideSpeed <= 0)
        {
            slideSpeed = 0f;
            speed = crouchSpeed;
        }
    }

    //Stopping the slide
    private void StopSlide()
    {
        controller.height = originalHeight;
        speed = baseSpeed;

        //Slide speed recovery
        slideSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(slideSpeed, slideSpeedStorage, Time.deltaTime * 2);
    }

    //Jumping mechanic
    private void Jump()
    {
        if (jump && isGrounded)
        {
            isJumping = true;
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }
    }

    private bool OnSlope()
    {
        if (isJumping)
        {
            return false;
        }

        RaycastHit hit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, controller.height / 2 * 5f))
            if(hit.normal != Vector3.up)
            {
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }

    //Stopping the slide if hitting object
    private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        if(hit.transform.tag == "SlideStop")
        {
            slideSpeed = 0f;
            speed = crouchSpeed;
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Have you tried modifying different wheel frictions?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your replay. Can you tell me what wheel frictions are?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WheelFrictionCurve.html and bottom of https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-WheelCollider.html

Comment: You need acceleration which is part of the Gravitational Force.  Friction is a force that goes in the opposite direction from the Gravitational force.

Comment: The problem i enounter is that i can't detect when i am on a slope and when i am on the normal flat ground.

Comment: @Tudoraster are you saying `OnSlope` doesn't return true when it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private bool OnSlope()
{
    if (isJumping)
    {
        return false;
    }

    RaycastHit hit;

    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, controller.height / 2 * 5f))
        if(hit.normal != Vector3.up)
        {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

One issue is comparing Vector3s which is bad practice, since they are arrays of floats. Even if the plane is completely planar, it might still return true due to what's known as 'floating point errors'. A better practice is to use:

```
Vector3.distance(hit.normal, Vector3.up) > .1f  // or some other small value;
```

Comment: Thanks  I will do that